# Decrypting Web Service traffic between our IIS and 3rd party site

Tags: iis, service, web, encryption

We're having trouble passing a token between our system (IIS) and an affiliate mall site using IIS Web Services.

I need to see the data that's being passed to debug the issue, but the traffic is encrypted. I understand the scenario of using either Wireshark or Fiddler2 if I had the private key...I doubt the partner will supply us with theirs...

So, is there a logging method on IIS7 or debug mode I can use to decrypt the traffic, or is there another method without the need of decryption. My feeling is we'll have to see if the partner has a debug mode they can flag so we can temporarily see the data in the packets.